# Jquery validation remote method with codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, validation, model-view-controller

As you can imagine I want to use remote method to avoid username and email recurrences. In the documentation, they use a php file which does the same thing a controller in mvc pattern.

Here is my problem; do I have to create another php page to do that(can't I do that with my existing controller) Either way, I get a `404 - Not found` or `500 - Internal server` error.

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
       email: {
           required: true,
           email: true,
           remote: "check-email.php" --> this file is what I mentioned about
       }
    }
});
```

and this is how I'm trying to do

```
uName:{
        required: true,
        minlength: 6,
        maxlength: 16,
        remote: {
           url: "user/validate", ---> controller/method
           type: "post"
        }
     },
```

I tried to create a php file, get the username and post it to controller manually, but I got a `404 - Not found` error again.

**EDIT 1**

Using "http://example.com/controller/method" or "method" for the url is reaching the same method. I don't get `404` error when I use them but I got `505` error.

**controller**

```
public function validate(){
    $uName = $this->input->post('uName');
    $isUNameCount = $this->user_model->isVarExists($uName);
    if($isUNameCount > 0){
        return json_encode(false);
    }
}
```

**model**

```
public function isVarExists($var){
    $query = $this->db
        ->select($var)
        ->where('user_name', $var)
        ->get('user')
        ->num_rows();
    return $query;
}
```

Please tell me if I do it wrong.

**SOLVED**

As always, the problem was somewhere else. The `select` in the query was getting wrong column name and the method validate in the controller needed to echo something instead of returning it.

Comment: Use the full uri `(http://blabla.com[/from/here])` and try again. If that doesn't work, check routing in your php application...

Comment: `select()` is wrong, you don't pass user input as field name

Comment: I was just editing the post, but thanks anyway